# Remote debugging an NT application from XP with Visual Studio 6.0

Tags: debugging, windows-xp, visual-c++-6, windows-nt

Is it possible to remote-debug a Visual C++ 6.0 application running on a Windows NT machine from a developer workstation running Windows XP?

If so, what is the procedure for doing so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- you can also use a newer version of Visual Studio.  As long as you have the PDB file for the target application it doesn't matter what version it was built with (well, VS6 might not understand a newer PDB, but backwards should be fine).

The remote debugging experience on newer VS versions is a lot smoother than old versions in my experience.  It is also easier to set up if you can arrange things so that you are attaching to an existing process that you have started manually rather than kicking off the process (avoid a lot of the path setup).